# Access MS SQL database from Android App

Tags: android, sql-server, database

I want my Android app to connect to an MS SQL database. I also tried Google, but only this link was a bit clear but I didn't understand it properly.

http://mob-programming.blogspot.com/search/label/How%20to%20connect%20and%20access%20SQL%20Database%20server%20from%20Android%20app%3F%3F

Can anyone give a links to tutorials on how to connect to MS SQL database from Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to connect to the MS SQL database using JDBC (Java Database Connectivity) and the MS SQL Database driver [available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx). I have not tried this personally and I'm not sure if it will be compatible on Android. In fact I doubt the driver will be compatible with Android but it might be worth a try.

Your best bet is to connect to the database using non-direct methods such as creating a web service which exposes the data you need.